# More variables = better fit?

Tags: statistics, regression

When fitting (let's say) a linear regression model, it is always true, that the more variables we include in our model, the better fit is (in R^2 sense)? I don't want to discuss here overfitting, problems with diagnostics etc. Just purely mathematical result.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more the number of variables we include in the model, the **seemingly** better the fit and higher the $R^2$. Yes it is true.  Every time you add a predictor to a model, the R-squared increases, even if due to chance alone. It never decreases. Consequently, a model with more terms may appear to have a better fit simply because it has more terms.But for this reason, we are supposed to interpret adjusted $R^2$.

The adjusted R-squared is a modified version of R-squared that has been adjusted for the number of predictors in the model. The adjusted R-squared increases only if the new term improves the model more than would be expected by chance. It decreases when a predictor improves the model by less than expected by chance.

Comment: But could you explain mathematically how new variable increases R^2? I just don't see it. Thank you a lot.